# Make user select a Radio Button in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

My model is :

```
public class Survey 
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage ="You must select an OK Option")]
    public string Abduction { get; set; }
```

and in the View, I am using :

```
        <td style="vertical-align:top" Width="60%">Is this OK ?</td>
        <td>
            @Html.RadioButton("OK", "Yes") Yes @Html.RadioButton("Ok", "No") No

        </td>
```

Do I need to `@Html.RadioButtonFor` or am I missing something else because the radio button validation is not activated.

For the submit button, I'm only doing

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign up</button>
```

and the BeginForm is :-

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("addsurvey","survey"))
{
```

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the name of property Abduction and use:

```
<td style="vertical-align:top" Width="60%">Is this OK ?</td>
<td>
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Abduction, "Yes") @:Yes
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Abduction, "No") @:No
</td>
```

or

```
<td style="vertical-align:top" Width="60%">Is this OK ?</td>
<td>
    @Html.RadioButton("Abduction ", "Yes") Yes 
    @Html.RadioButton("Abduction ", "No") No 
</td>
```

Comment: What do you mean? Not showing "You must select an OK Option" or something else? Please explain what is the problem, because it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking when you write "doesn't work."

Comment: If I click on the submit button (added in), the page is submitted without requiring a radio button be selected.    The Validation doesn't kick in and the value of Abduction is null instead of Yes or No.

Comment: If you do not want to submit then you have to enable client side validation

Comment: Is it a flag setting or do I need to write the Javascript code to validate the required fields?

Answer (score 0):

The page will submit because nothing is there to block it from submitting. You can then check `ModelState.IsValid` to see if what was submitted was usable/allowed/valid, like this:

```
public ActionResult addsurvey(Survey srv)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // OK: Save, Proceed and/or Redirect
    }
    else
    {
        // not OK: show View again
        return View(srv);  // or: View("ViewName", srv);
    }
}
```

In the View, make sure to use `@Html.ValidationSummary()` which will show the user why ModelState was not valid.

Comment: When I go to return View(srv), it goes to /addsurvey rather than refreshing the page.

Comment: I've got it reloading but no validation messages are appearing and the options I selected before are no longer selected.

Comment: Does your View start with `@model Survey` ? Also, make sure to use `Html.RadioButtonFor(m => ...)` as MegaTron suggested.

Comment: Yes and Yes.
@model Project.Models.Survey
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Abduction, "Yes") Yes
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Abduction, "No") No
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Abduction)

Comment: That looks okay, I'm afraid that without seeing the whole it's gonna be hard to make further suggestions.